# Left join and concatenated column displaying blanks instead of (null)

Tags: mysql, left-join, nvl

I'm doing a left outer join of two tables where the `manager_id` of one table can be joined to values in another table's `employee_id`.  The query I wrote runs, but I am trying to use `nvl()` to replace the null values with the string 'NO_MANAGER'.  However, this is what I get instead:

```
select d.DEPARTMENT_ID, d.DEPARTMENT_NAME, nvl(d.manager_id, 0) AS MANAGER_ID, d.LOCATION_ID, 
nvl(e.first_name || ' ' || e.LAST_NAME,'NO_MANAGER') AS NAME 
from departments d
left join employees e on d.manager_id = e.EMPLOYEE_ID order by d.DEPARTMENT_ID;
```

This is what is returned: 
[image]

Am I missing something or will `nvl()` not work in this case?

Comment: try `nvl(e.first_name,'NO_MANAGER')`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, is there a way to maintain the columns being concatenated and have this still work?

Comment: first of all nvl is from oracle, why you tag mysql?.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you:

```
select d.DEPARTMENT_ID, d.DEPARTMENT_NAME,
 ifnull(d.manager_id, 0) AS MANAGER_ID, d.LOCATION_ID, 
if(e.first_name is null or e.LAST_NAME is null,'NO_MANAGER',
 concat(e.first_name, ' ', e.LAST_NAME)) AS NAME 
from departments d
left join employees e on d.manager_id = e.EMPLOYEE_ID 
order by d.DEPARTMENT_ID;
```

?

Comment: When I try to run this, I get a "missing right parenthesis" error

Comment: Are you using MySQL? I just tried the query above with MySQL after creating the tables, and the parser took it. Besides, "missing right parenthesis" does not sound like an error from MySQL parser, which does not try to guess what exactly is wrong with your syntax, it just gives you the location where it stumbled.

Comment: apologies...I forgot to clarify that I was using Oracle Sql Developer when doing this

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that displays the results I was looking for:

```
TRIM(LEADING FROM e.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || COALESCE(e.LAST_NAME, 'No Manager')) AS "NAME"
```

Comment: for study porpouse, take a look to my answer, and understand what is happen with the first query :).

Answer (score 0):

This happen because when you put:

```
e.first_name || ' ' || e.LAST_NAME
```

automaticaly your null value concatenated with string convert into string value different to null, this is an implicit cast, and nvl can't find null.

You can try this (or another solution of course)

```
select d.DEPARTMENT_ID, d.DEPARTMENT_NAME, nvl(d.manager_id, 0) AS MANAGER_ID, d.LOCATION_ID, 
nvl(e.first_name,'NO_MANAGER') || nvl(e.LAST_NAME,'') AS NAME 
from departments d
left join employees e on d.manager_id = e.EMPLOYEE_ID order by d.DEPARTMENT_ID;
```